# How to use SQL subquery using a concat-ed parameter (the backend operations are in a class)?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, subquery

I'm creating a practice project to help me organizing things by placing them into container crates.

Each crate will contain items. I want the program to show me what items are inside the crate when I enter the PK of the crate.

I have 3 tables:

**crateContTbl**:

```
    [crateContTbl]  INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [crateBC_FK]    VARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [invBC_FK]      VARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [crateQty]      INT          NULL,
    [crateLocation] VARCHAR (50) NULL,
```

**crateTbl**:

```
    [crateBC] VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
```

**invTbl**:

```
    [invBC]    VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [itemName] VARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [itemDesc] VARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [itemPic]  IMAGE        NULL,
```

I made the backend operations in a class where I take a parameter from form1 and have that do a wildcard search.

The `Backend` class method returns datatables but, the one with the subquery returns nothing. It works if I give it a specific value.

The wildcard search works as a query that I use to show me search items for all the entries, but I think writing it as a subquery requires something else?

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT invTbl.invBC, invTbl.ItemName FROM invTbl WHERE invTbl.invBC = (SELECT crateContTbl.invBC_FK FROM crateContTbl WHERE crateContTbl.crateBC_FK = " + txtSearch + ")";
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to use like operator in the sub-query like below

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT invTbl.invBC, invTbl.ItemName FROM invTbl WHERE invTbl.invBC = (SELECT crateContTbl.invBC_FK FROM crateContTbl WHERE crateContTbl.crateBC_FK like '%'" + txtSearch + "'%')";
```

Comment: I used LIKE on a previous attempt. It works as a query, but not as a subquery for some reason. Idk why...

Comment: Can you try to keep in operator --> "WHERE invTbl.invBC =" to "WHERE invTbl.invBC in" (your subsquery)